# Autogenerating xaml ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have an application in which I'm using a specific ResourceDictionary for my strings and I need to duplicate the keys of that ResourceDictionary in a class as string constants. While it's easy to just copy and paste, I'm expecting around 350 resource strings, and having to manage both files having all the content isn't an option.

I want to code an app that would have a Key/Value grid for which the user would enter the values, and that app would write in the Xaml file and in the .cs constant class. I have no problem with the .cs file, but is there a way to write to a xaml file without having to clear the file before writing the contents of the new file?

Thanks

Comment: This should be built in to Visual Studio. I often find myself doing this sort of thing manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a T4 template that uses a simple designer (WPF usercontrol) or xml file to generate the xaml and C# files.

[Excellent T4 tutorials by Oleg Sych](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/)

[Here is how to generate multiple files with T4](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/)

Comment: Thanks mate, this has everything I need to solve my issue. I hadn't heard of T4 before, this most likely will help me in many ways. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I use ReSharper 7 beta in VS11 (though older versions have the same functionality) to create a Template which at least allows you to lessen the keystrokes required.

Comment: Sadly for me ReSharper wasn't an option, I have limited resources in my current context